how can I find a good user agent for my botpyhton?
I have a python bot that monitors this website in the background, sending requests
the site
https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplustiem/index.html
, and now it blocked my user agent
my user ;"User-Agent": "DuckDuckBot-Https/1.1"
how can I find a luser agent that works without problems on this site?
